# Django admin: allowing some HTML in user input

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-admin

By default, the Django admin strips away all HTML tags from user input. I'd like to allow a small subset of tags, say `<a>`. What's the easiest way to do this? I know about `allow_tags`, but it's deprecated. I also want to be careful about manually marking strings as safe that aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If external library isn't a burden for you, then you must try [django-bleach](https://django-bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), it will suffice your requirement. It returns valid HTML that only contains your specified allowed tags.

Configuration:
in settings.py

```
BLEACH_ALLOWED_TAGS = ['p', 'b', 'i', 'u', 'em', 'strong', 'a']
BLEACH_ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES = ['href', 'title', 'style']
BLEACH_STRIP_TAGS = True
```

Use cases:
1. In your models:

```
from django import models
from django_bleach.models import BleachField

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    content = BleachField()
```

2. In your forms:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = BleachField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']
```

3. In your templates:

   {% load bleach_tags %}

   {{ unsafe_html|bleach }}

for more usage, I suggest you must read the documentation. Its quite easy and straight forward.

> [documentation](https://django-bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format_html()` or `mark_safe()` in place of `allow_tags`. Although, like you were saying, `mark_safe()` probably isn't a good idea for user input.

`format_html()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html
`mark_safe()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe

Comment: That will only work if the HTML parts aren't entered by the user, as far as I can tell.