# Django seems to be stripping html when I try and insert it into a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, django

I'm finding this really strange. When I try and insert data into the database it will strip out all but `<p>` html tags?!

Example text that I'm trying to insert:

```
<p>Facebook This link should show up... Facebook&nbsp;Facebook&nbsp;CHANGE&nbsp; <a href="http://www.f.com" target="_blank">CHAN</a></p>
```

I'm printing the above text to the console before I'm committing, like so:

```
print job

if commit:
    job.save()

return job
```

Then when I go into my `mysql` and view what was inserted I get the following:

```
<p>Facebook This link should show up... Facebook Facebook CHANGE CHAN</p>
```

As you can see it's stripped out  the `<a href='http://www.f.com` and left the text inside the `<a` tag (CHAN).

Any ideas why this may be happening? It seems very strange that, for some reason, the html is being stripped.

Comment: You need to give more details. this `job` is it a model instance? can you show us the model class declaration?  which field do you assign that html to? have you tried assigning this text manually in the console?

ex: `job.html_field = '<p>Facebook ......</p>` then `job.save()` ?

Comment: Hang on will try that, if it still strips it, then it must be a mysql problem. Will update answer with the model after I try. @Ramast

Comment: @Ramast - I answered my own question. Turned out I was using ```django-bleach```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a `BleachField()` from [Django-bleach](http://django-bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) and the settings for it weren't allowing `Links`! So I had to go into my `settings.py` to change them.

I am new to `Django` and am working on a prebuilt project with tonnes of code! So it was a hard find.

Anyway, checkout this link for more about it: [Django admin: allowing some HTML in user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34137798/django-admin-allowing-some-html-in-user-input/34194645)